# How to query cardano blockchain related data like createwallet, getnewaddress, getbalance , sendtoaddress

Tags: cardano-cli, wallet, blockchain

I have done cardano node setup and sync it 100% And also install an cardano wallet using CLI. Now I want to interact with cardano using node js, can someone please tell me how we can do basic operation like create wallet, getnewaddress, transafer or sendtoaddress , getbalance. or which libraries we can use. or Are there any RPC method by using that i can query blockchain related data.